# How to reduce a JPG image size in C#?

Tags: c#, image-resizing, bmp, encoder

Below is my code to capture a screenshot. I tried to use "EncoderParameters" to reduce the file size but it seems doesn't work.

My screen resolution: 1920 x 1080:

- Without Encoder setting, just save the bitmap image directly: 75KB
- Encoder JPG 100%: 350KB
- Encoder JPG 50%: 92KB
- Encoder JPG 0%: 40KB (Can't see anything with this setting)

Is there anyway to reduce the image size less than 10KB? If not, what is the best method to reduce the file size as much as possible?

```
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
   Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp as Image);

   graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

   ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

   System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
   System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

   EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

   EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
   myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
   bmp.Save("TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

   myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
   myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
   bmp.Save("TestPhotoQualityHundred.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

   myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);
   myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
   bmp.Save("TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: How about reducing the resolution and not just encoding quality? You are trying to compress something like 6mb pixel data into 10kb for 1920x1080. Unless its a monochrome image it gonna be difficult to encode any near-original appearance.

Comment: check out this answer it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441098/how-to-resize-image-with-different-resolution

Comment: @grek40 Yeah, reducing the resolution is a good solution here. I don't mind if the image is small, as long as it's readable.

Comment: You gotta be more specific. I just tried with a screenshot into Paint.Net and got the following: below 50% image size, the smaller fonts become unreadable. With 50% size I'd still have 10.5kb file size when chosing to save with 0% quality (=unreadable). If we are talking about the same thing I think you ask for the impossible. So if you need something readable at 10kb, you need to be VERY specific about your image constraints - generally its not gonna happen.

Comment: Reducing the resolution to half width x half height would reduce the size to 1/4. Encoding using 50% (don't try any less) will then give you 25KB readable image (kind of). This is the best you can get with JPG. If you still want to get lower than this, try other formats, otherwise this is your limit with JPG

Comment: Another thought: if your goal is readable text, your best bet is copying text instead of images ;)

Comment: jpg is never readable and small. png with reduced colors is a better idea..

Comment: any solution so far ?